# Align indents of list of figures and list of theorems

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, memoir, thmtools

I am sure this is answered already somewhere but I did not find it, sorry.

I am using `memoir` with the `\listoftheorems` of the `thmtools` package and I use `\listoffigures` (and `\listoftables`). For some reason the horizontal alignment of the entries do not match. The numbers and the actual text entries are slightly more to the right.

How can I adjust the horizontal alignmentof the entries in`\listoftheorems` to match `\listoffigures`?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter] 

\begin{document}

    \listoffigures

    \listoftheorems

    \begin{theorem}
        My first theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        My second theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{figure}
        My favorite figure.
        \caption{My favorite figure's caption.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could patch `\listoftheorems`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\listoftheorems}
  {1.5em}
  {\cftfigureindent}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\listoftheorems}
  {1.5em}
  {\cftfigureindent}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftheorems
\begin{theorem}
    My first theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
    My second theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{figure}
    My favorite figure.
    \caption{My favorite figure's caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```